# how to solve connection between DB and Application

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, spring, hibernate

Currently I am working on a project using spring, hibernate with Microsoft SQL, in this project there is a part to generate invoice. When I run this part to generate invoice it take around 5 to 15 min then I retrieve invoice List from Db and show it in UI. I got exception after it process for around 7 to 10 min. 
Note: When I check in Db , invoice is already generated.
How can I solve this issue?

The exception as follows:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
```

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.191.19, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Address already in use: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".

Comment: some other application is already listening on the port no. 1433

Answer (score 0):

I think the driver may be the problem.
Try using jtds driver instead of microsoft dirver.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection url pattern.Here is sample connection url pattern.

```
     jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Comment: <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
  <property name="url"
   value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.191.50:1433;DatabaseName=ExxonMobil" />
  <property name="username" value="sa" />
  <property name="password" value="welcome" />
 </bean>

Comment: hi i am using this in config.xml

Comment: @sudo your config.xml has no problem.Try placing a copy of your SQLServer db driver in your WEB-INF/lib folder.